# Hyperapp Project Console Error

Tags: javascript, linux, hyperapp

When I run npm run watch, I'm not getting any updates from the hyperapp app.js file to the browser page.  The only thing that is loading is the CSS.

This is what my console says in the png file.  Any possible solutions with the provided info?[Console Error information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jorQL.png)

The link to the project files are here: https://github.com/codingphasedotcom/hyperapp-starterkit

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Yes, sir.  It's located at this link: https://github.com/codingphasedotcom/hyperapp-starterkit

Comment: Please take a moment to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Please try to include all the relevant information pertaining to your code and problem within your question itself.  Please copy the text of the error your are receiving and post that in your question as well rather than an image of the error.